# How to implement custom made Methods in Java that will be common to many classes?

Tags: java, class, methods, macros, functional-programming

Need something in Java that can hold my custom made methods that are going to be common for many other classes that I'm using in my project.

What needs to be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Util` class and in it make methods, like :

```
 public class Util {
    /*
     * Checks if the given string is a relevant feature
     * returns boolean true if input string qualifies as a relevant feature
    */
    static public boolean isFeature(String s) {

       List<String> irrelevant = Arrays.asList( "a", 
                                                "an",
                                                "but",
                                                "how",
                                                "will",
                                                "this",
                                                "that",
                                                "them",
                                                "they",
                                                "there",
                                                "these"
                                );

       return !(irrelevant.contains(s));
    }
 }
```

and on need of such common methods use them as :

```
Boolean result = Util.isFeature("arbitraryWord");
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the methods you are talking about are some general utility methods, for example something like `getMax(int a, int b)`.

If that is the case, you could just create a class with your helper-methods as static methods.

For example:

```
public class Util
{
    public static int getMax(int a, int b) { ... }
}
```

Comment: yes your are getting it right, but this is not working as a solution. Other class files are not aware of those static methods.

Comment: I don't understand. Whereever you want to use your common methods you just call `Util.commonMethod()`. What do you mean by other class files are not aware of those static methods?

Answer (score 1):

Put your methods in an `abstract class` and have all the classes `extend` that class. Alternatively, if you're ok with just defining the method signatures (input types and output types, basically) you can use an interface and have your classes implement it.

Comment: Java allows extending from only a single class; Already extended my class using JFrame, but need custom and common methods too for the same 'already extended once' class

Comment: @cseav If all your classes extend JFrame you can make a JFrame sub class that has your methods and extend that in place of Jframe and all your common methods are inherited. Wouldn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an interface. Unlike class inheritance in Java, which only allows you to extend a class from a single superclass, a class can implement any number of interfaces. For example, lets say the common method you want to use is called commonMethod, and two of the classes you want to use this method are called Class1 and Class2. Then your code would look something like this:

```
public interface CommonMethods{
void commonMethod(Object anyInputs);
}

public class Class1 extends JFrame, implements CommonMethods{
@override 
public void commonMethod(Object anyInputs){
//the contents of your method go here.
}
}

public class Class2 extends JFrame, implements CommonMethods{
@override 
public void commonMethod(Object anyInputs){
//the contents of your method go here.
}
}
```

Alternatively, if you plan on using the exact same implementation of your commonMethod in every single class that uses it, you can use a default implementation, which is new in Java 8. In that case, the above code would look simpler:

```
public interface CommonMethods{
default void commonMethod(Object anyInputs){
//method body goes here
}
}

public class Class1 extends JFrame, implements CommonMethods{
//method is already built in
}

public class Class2 extends JFrame, implements CommonMethods{
//method is already built in
}
```

I hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: thanks, this new feature of Java serves my purpose, but since I'm working with Java SE 7, it is required that I follow the solution provided above by greenkeeper

Comment: ok, in that case you cannot use the default implementation. Still, I would personally recommended you use interfaces in a situation like this. Indeed, it is exactly what they were made for. This kind of development is called "Design by contract". For more, see this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract

Comment: but once a Contract is designed, it will be required to unnecessarily write the empty skeletons for the methods that are not in use, this will make code look tedious

Comment: well if you don't want a class to implement that method, simply dont declare the implementation in your class definition. And if you are referring to the fact that you may want to use only some of the methods in your interface, it is recommended to only declare methods in an interface that will be used together and keep your interfaces small, as you can always join them or implement multiple ones.